# Sharing large files efficiently on web link

Tags: asp.net

I would like to provide a link on my web site to download a large file. This should be done with scale in mind. What is best efficient way as of today?

Of course i can do a classic way:

```
<a href="//download.myserver.com/largefile.zip" title="Download via HTTP" >
```

The problem with this approach is: i dont want traffic to my server to explode with downloads. So I would rather redirect to external hosting for this large file. What is best way to host this file then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid download traffic to your server, then I personally suggest using Azure Blob Storage. There is lots of documentation and client libraries for .Net. It removes download traffic from your site and the security concerns of hosting files and moves them to the Azure cloud which is very secure to say the least.

If you want the files to be publicly available to anyone, then make a public container, get the url of the file you want and place it in the anchor tag, otherwise you may need to familiarise yourself with the blob leasing (plenty of documentation too). Though like most things it is not free. The silver lining is you only pay for what you use.

**You can get started here.**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet

Disclaimer,
I do not work for Microsoft, nor I do not benefit form this. This is just a personal opinion based on previous experiences and projects.

Comment: thank you, this might be a good option. Are there free global file servers with similar purpose?

Comment: The popular file hosting sites such as Dropbox, Google drive and more all offer some free space, along with an API you can use to get file urls for your anchor tags.

Comment: I was thinking about Dropbox(i use it to exchange files with people) but I am not sure if it is ok to use it for web sites and commercial. I am sure dropbox is ment just for simple user file sharing.

Comment: Sadly, you are right. If you want to use it commercially then you will have to pay for a license. I very much doubt you'll find a free file hosting service for commercial sites. They all need to keep the lights on somehow!